# Multiline text field using angular limitTo or slice or filter

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an HTML field which is supposed to display the first couple of lines of a text message that was sent to/from you most recently, similar to messages on an iphone. I want max two lines of text, the end of the second line is cut off using ellipsis. I can only hold 45 characters per line the way it's formatted. Preferably there would be a way to do word break properly but I haven't found that yet either.

I'm also planning on building this using ionic/cordova so I can't rely on pure css, scss or any other webkit trickery so I'm attempting to do this only using angular. I'm really close but I can't get it.

My solution is essentially taking my messages text, `{{message.text}}`, and using `limitTo` or the `slice` method to take the first 45 characters of the returned array text, then on a second line right below it, the next 45 characters after those first 45.

```
                <div class="row row-center">
                    <div class="col" style="padding:0px">
                        <div style="">
                        {{ message.text | limitTo: 45 }}<br />
                        {{ message.text.slice(45,90) }}
                        {{ message.text.length > 45 ? '...' : ''}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I understand the problem here, which is that I'm using the same set of results, in the first line I'm getting the first 45, the second line I'm getting the first 90, then from the end I'm taking 46...this doesn't make sense I realize but I feel like I'm close, any guidance appreciated.

EDIT:
I think I just figured it out, using slice (changed above)! Now does anyone have an idea about how to do this wordwise?

Comment: using a filter will not modify the actual model on the LHS. So you are always working on the same message.text. So with your logic `message.text.length > 90` should make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why cant you use limitTo:90 (why do you want to use it as 45 twice????) and enable word wrap in the field where the message will be displayed.

use limitTo in your controller like,

```
$filter('limitTo')(input, limit) 
$filter('limitTo')(message.text, 90) //In your case limit is 90
```

In your case , 
First 45 characters : `$filter('limitTo')(message.text, 45)`
Next 45 characeter : `$filter('limitTo')($filter('limitTo')(message.text, 90),-45);`

In HTML :

```
{{message.text | limitTo:45}}
{{message.text | limitTo:90 | limitTo:-45}} //This will fetch first 90 characters and removes first 45 from it giving you next 45 characters
```

Comment: it has to be two lines of text, so can you think of a way to get the first 45 characters to be on one line and the next 45 on the second without css?

Comment: yes! this is actually what I had previously, but then replaced it in my edit which is now above in my question. thanks! do you have any ideas about doing word wrap by chance? The closest thing I've found is this filter, https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/653#issuecomment-3576805 but I'd have to rewrite it a bit to just get the wordwise functionality I think?

Comment: `<p class="test">youverylongtext</p> , write a css for test as .test{word-wrap: break-word;}`